# How to access the subversion repository through WebDAV/DeltaV?

Tags: linux, svn, redmine, webdav

I installed and set up BitNami Redmine Stack and created the repository:

```
svnadmin create /var/svn/repository0/
```

I use basic authentication.

Part of httpd.conf:

```
<Location>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/svn
   AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth.passwd
   Require valid-user
   Satisfy Any
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn/authz
</Location>
```

Part of svn-auth.passwd:

```
htpasswd -c -m /etc/svn-auth.htpasswd someuser
someuser:$apr1$bTN...
```

authz:

```
[/]
* = r

[repository0:/]
someuser = rw
```

When I go through this url: `http://remote-linux-host:81/svn/repository0/` I get the following:

[image]

I enter my credentials and see:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /svn/repository0/ on this server.
```

For this url `http://remote-linux-host:81/svn/` I get:

```
<D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable></D:error>
```

What I have in error.log:

```
...
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:17 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: /var/svn/authz:22: Option expected
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:17 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Access denied: 'someuser' GET svn:/repository0
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:20 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: /var/svn/authz:22: Option expected
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:20 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Access denied: 'someuser' GET svn:/repository0
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:38 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: /var/svn/authz:22: Option expected
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:38 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Access denied: 'someuser' GET svn:/repository0
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:46 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/var/svn/format': No such file or directory
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:46 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:46 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
[Wed Dec 12 15:16:46 2012] [error] [client ..ip...] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2]
```

I made some small changes in the `authz` file:

```
[groups]
developers = someuser

[repository0:/]
@developers = rw
```

Now, when I go through this url again `http://remote-linux-host:81/svn/repository0/` I get the following:

```
<D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable></D:error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave read/write access for the user who runs the Apache and now everything is OK.

[image]

Comment: BTW, with `Satisfy Any` you have don't get auth-request on read. Check it